# Change of "home office" address while on F-1 STEM OPT extension and awaiting H-1B lottery results

Tags: immigration, h1-visa

My situation is as follows:

I'm on F-1 STEM OPT working remotely from Dallas, Texas for a Company
C with headquarters in state Y in the USA.

Company C filed H-1B for me with location as Dallas and location Y as
two possible work locations on LCA. I'm still waiting for the results of the H-1B lottery.

Now my apartment lease in Dallas, Texas is getting over and I
want to relocate to state Z for  personal reasons.

On STEM OPT, If I move to a new apartment, I have to update the SEVIS
portal within 10 days of that change.

Will this change of address have any impact on the pending H1-B petition? I was not able to find any information regarding this on the web.

Until what point in time are F-1 STEM OPT rules applicable? When do the LCA/H-1B rules kick in?

Will LCA H-1B rules kick in only if

1. The H-1B petition gets picked in lottery and 2. The date is October 1st 2018?

My opinion is as follows:

As long as there is no change of status, I will continue to be dictated by the STEM OPT laws, in other words these LCA requirements are applicable to employees on H-1B and nobody else. So If my petition gets picked in the lottery, then I will ask my company to apply for an LCA amendment with change of address before October 1, 2018. Because even if they file an amendment now and the petition doesn't get picked in
the lottery it will be a waste of money for them.

H-1B visa and its rules are valid only from October 1, 2018 in my
opinion.

Also based on this : https://www.uscis.gov/news/alerts/uscis-draft-guidance-when-file-amended-h-1b-petition-after-simeio-solutions-decision

> If your H-1B employee is moving to a new job location within the same MSA or area of intended employment a new LCA is not required.

So does that mean, in the event that my H-1B gets picked in the lottery and if I were to find a new apartment somewhere within Dallas Texas, I can avoid the LCA amendment ?